# how to search by mobile number using hibernate criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, servlets

In this program I want to get the detail by `mobileNumber`. When we come here `Customer customer = (Customer)cr.uniqueResult();` (line number 28) then it goes directly to the catch block and throws this exception:

> Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.TransactionException:
>   Transaction not successfully started  at
>   org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:100)
>     at com.TestByGSTNumber.main(TestByGSTNumber.java:36)

```
public class TestByNumber {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Configuration cfg=new Configuration();
        cfg.configure("com/util/hibernate.cfg.xml");
        SessionFactory factory=null;
        Session session=null;
        Transaction transaction=null;
        try{
            session =  SessionFinder.getSession();
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(Customer.class);
            cr.add(Restrictions.eq("mobileNumber","12345"));
           Customer customer= (Customer)cr.uniqueResult();
            System.out.println("value"+customer.getCity());


        }catch(Exception e){
            if(transaction  != null)transaction.rollback();
        }
        finally{
            if(transaction!=null)transaction.commit();;
            session.flush();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Java is not Javascript. You should be aware of this and set the tags properly.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, based on the information you did provide, the exception is being thrown by the `if (transaction != null) transaction.commit();` line. Otherwise it wouldn't be shown due to the exception catching clause.

What I figure out is that, for some other reason the `uniqueResult()` call is throwing an exception (for now put a `e.printStackTrace()` as first line in the exception block, just silencing it is preventing you to know what is happening).

After catching the exception and rolling back the transaction, the execution continues to the finally block that tries to commit the exact same transaction rolled back a moment ago.

It would be better if you test the transaction, rather than just check for `null`. So test for, `if (transaction != null && transaction.isActive()) {...}` to check if is valid the transaction reference you have. Check on the [Hibernate reference](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Transaction.html#isActive()).

I suggest you to the `session` and `transaction` acquisition outside the `try` block. That way the statements protected by the exception handling block will be related only to the business logic operations, not about the  code needed for preparing the execution.